# How to fetch documents that are matching the specified term in a inner object in elasticsearch?

Tags: database, elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack

I'm having an elastic search index which has the following document sample in it :

```
{
"height": 2824,
 "details": {
      'gomathi':{'name':'gomathi','age':10},
      'janu':{'name':'janu','age':20}
   }
}
```

The data are pushed into elasticsearch dynamically from user. My goal is to fetch all documents that are containing name as gomathi.

**Expected output:**

Return documents having the 'gomathi' key in 'details' JSON object.

How to solve this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I assume `details` is a nested field in mapping. You could use `inner_hits` in a nested query for the requirement explained.

Please take a look at [inner_hits](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.5/search-request-body.html#request-body-search-inner-hits) and [nested documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.5/nested.html).